# Qt 5.5 using C++, removing and item from ComboBox is removing all items before the item as well

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, qt5.5

Working on a program where 6 combobox's have relative data, once an index is selected, the others shouldn't be able to select it, hence I'm just removing it from the index on the others, however in practice it is removing the index plus every index before it for some reason.  Any idea why?

```
void AssignStatsWindow::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged()
{
    ui->comboBox_2->removeItem(ui->comboBox->currentIndex());  //these should remove 1 index but removes many
    ui->comboBox_3->removeItem(ui->comboBox->currentIndex());
    ui->comboBox_4->removeItem(ui->comboBox->currentIndex());
    ui->comboBox_5->removeItem(ui->comboBox->currentIndex());
    ui->comboBox_6->removeItem(ui->comboBox->currentIndex());

    for (int i = ui->comboBox->count(); i >= 0; --i) //removes all but newly selected index, seems to be working fine
    {
        if (i != ui->comboBox->currentIndex()) {
            ui->comboBox->removeItem(i);
        }
    }
}
```

`comboBox` is the one having the `indexChanged`  and triggering the code, `comboBox_2` through 6 are the others that need adjust and are 'over-removing' indexes.  Once I get this first one working correctly it should be easy to build the rest of the `indexChanged` for the rest of the `comboBox`es. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Qt 5.5 documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#removeItem):

> Removes the item at the given index from the combobox. This will update the current index if the index is removed.

---

> in practice it is removing the index plus every index before it for some reason. Any idea why?

It seems that the work to remove an item is being performed in a slot that responds to the `currentIndexChanged` signal. The above documentation states removing an item will change the current index of the combo box which will result in the slot being triggered many times, thereby removing many items.

Comment: I see, so my for loop at the end its causing more triggers then since the index is changing.  That makes sense. Time to think of a new way to do this.

Comment: @StackAttack I'd need to know a little more about how all the signals and slots are connected but there is a [`blockSignals`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals) function on every `QObject` that can be enabled and disabled to handle situations similar to this.

Comment: I managed to figure it out by reading a bit more - "There are two signals emitted if the current item of a combobox changes, currentIndexChanged() and activated(). currentIndexChanged() is always emitted regardless if the change was done programmatically or by user interaction, while activated() is only emitted when the change is caused by user interaction."  -  So the solution was to simply use activated() instead of currentIndexChanged() and wala, the algo is going to work going forward. Thanks for your help!